# Visual Studio 2010 debugger is not working "Error while trying to run project: Method does not exists."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am suddenly facing this problem with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. whenever i try to start a project with debugging, getting error message in a popup window - "Error while trying to run project: Method does not exists."  However I can able to start this project well without debugging. I am getting this error with all projects which have worked fine previously in debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried "Build"->"Clean Solution" before building?

Comment: yes, tried but not working.

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio? It should be an option in "Add/Remove Programs" or "Programs and Features" (depending on your OS) when you right-click the appropriate Visual Studio entry.

Comment: just now re-installed, still not working :(

Comment: You could try moving the [.suo file](http://briannoyes.net/2008/05/10/the-evil-suo-file-fighting-and-winning-with-visual-studio/) out of the project's directory. VS should re-create it as needed.

Comment: I have deleted the .suo file and tried, but still getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2010 debugger is not working “Error while trying to run ... facing this problem with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. whenever i try to start a project with debugging, getting error message in a popup window - "Error while trying to run ... You could try moving the .suo file out of the project's directory